# how to auto select a category on this website from URL

Tags: html, web

i am trying to reduce website load time on my browser (m not the owner of website). I need "whitelist" category auto selected when i load the URL. is there any way??
also is there a way to block the heavy background on this website.

https://shack.gamingapeclub.com/

Comment: You can turn off auto-loading images in your browser, and you'll need something like selenium or imacros to auto click.

Answer (score 0):

It's a single page application and gets all of the records at the beginning; Meaning it doesn't matter if you enable a category or not. You have downloaded everything anyway even if you are not seeing them.

You can check the network tab in the dev console and inspect the APIs. [This](https://gaming-ape-club.herokuapp.com/listing?tags=96d775b6-e0ad-4678-b91e-23cef74788a0) is the API of that particular *whitelist* category. If this data is sufficient, you can check this api directly, instead of the client itself.